# adding a node to a qroof in tikz-qtree

Tags: trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I need a node in the head element of a qroof in tikz-qtree (using tikz-qtree-compat). I need the 'np' to be a node so I can draw an arrow to it. However, the following breaks:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [ .TP I [ .T' T[past] [ .\node(vp){vP}; { } [ .v' v\\saw [ .VP { } [ .V' V(saw) \qroof{a man}.\node(nP){nP} ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error is: `Undefined control sequence \node(nP)nP`.

Any ideas on how to accomplish a node there?

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  That would not only clarify the question but also help to test that the solution does indeed fix your problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill: sorry. I added one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are limits to the direct compatibility of `qtree` commands. The `\qroof` command is emulated with the `\node` command, which is why it can't use a `\node` as its label. But  `tikz-qtree` has its own method for doing roof structures.   You should use this for more complex roofs:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}} % to allow linebreaks
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [ .TP I [ .T\1 T\\{[past]} [ .\node(vp){vP}; { } [ .v\1 v\\saw 
      [ .VP { } [ .V\1 V\\(saw) [.\node(nP){nP}; \edge[roof]; {a man} ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

P.S. I also cleaned up some of your formatting: you should use `\1` for formatting bar levels instead of just `'`.