# Trees: adjusting arrows and roofs

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

How can I ensure that the arrow from `$t_2$` curves below "of"? How can I use `\qroof{some company}.DP` and yet still have the arrow pointing to it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.S 
  [.DP [.D Every ] 
    [.NP [.DP$_1$ \node (ne) {PRO}; ]  
        [.NP $\lambda_1$ 
            [.NP \node (ue) {some company}; 
                [.S 
                    [.$\lambda_1$     ] 
                    [.NP    [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {t$_{1}$} ;  ] 
                            [.N$’$ [.N representative ] [.PP [.P of ] 
                                            [. \node [circle,draw] (le) {t$_{2}$} ;   ]
                                            ]
                            ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
  [.VP [.V saw ] [. \qroof{a sample}.DP ]]
]
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:6) and +(south:6) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:3) and +(south:3) .. (ne);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.VP John [.V$’$ [.V loves ] \qroof{the man}.DP ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing the anchor (where the arrow from `$t_2$` comes from) can fix the   colliding line. Something like `\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south:5) and +(south:6) .. (ue);` should work.  I don't quite understand the second part of the question, could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision happens because the *of* node is along the path between the *t<sub>2</sub>* node and the control point you specify with `south west:6`. (See my answer to your question [Drawing node arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251006/drawing-node-arrows/251040#251040) for more information about how these control points work.)

[image]

You need to move the first control point so that the *of* node is out of the way of this path. It's pretty easy to do this by changing the `south west` to `south`, but I would also recommend shortening the distance to get a better looking arrow. And as I mentioned in [Drawing node arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251006/drawing-node-arrows/251040#251040), you can get finer control over the position of control points if you use the xy-coordinate system rather than the compass point system.

To label a roof node so that you can refer to it (e.g., as the endpoint of an arrow), use the following syntax: `[.DP \edge[roof]; \node (ue) {some company}; ]`. (See [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144312/42880) to [More efficient way to draw movement arrow to roof in tikz-qtree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144311/more-efficient-way-to-draw-movement-arrow-to-roof-in-tikz-qtree/144312#144312).) This actually means that `(ue)` is the node under the roof. It is also possible to add a `tikz` label to the roof's syntactic label (DP) (see [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34959/42880) to [adding a node to a qroof in tikz-qtree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34954/adding-a-node-to-a-qroof-in-tikz-qtree)), but it's harder in most cases to get the arrows to look nice that way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
    show control points/.style={
        decoration={show path construction, curveto code={
                \draw [blue, dashed]
                    (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
                    node [at end, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
                \draw [blue, dashed]
                    (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
                    node [at start, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.S 
  [.DP [.D Every ] 
    [.NP [.DP_1 \node (ne) {PRO}; ]  
        [.NP $\lambda_1$ 
            [.NP
                [.DP \edge[roof]; \node (ue) {some company}; ]
                [.S 
                    [.$\lambda_1$     ] 
                    [.NP    [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {t$_{1}$} ;  ] 
                            [.N$’$ [.N representative ] [.PP [.P of ] 
                                            [. \node [circle,draw] (le) {t$_{2}$} ;   ]
                                            ]
                            ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
  [.VP [.V saw ] [. \qroof{a sample}.DP ]]
]
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->, show control points] (le)..controls +(-0,-3) and +(0,-4) .. (ue); % equivalent to +(south:3) and +(south:4)
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:3) and +(south:3) .. (ne);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting out the colliding arrow from `$t_2$` to `\node (ue) {some company};` can be achieved by altering the anchor from which the arrow comes from. From `+(south west:6)` to `+(south:3)`. A larger number can be used here if desired.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34959/73570%22This%20answer%22) shows that `\qroof` is not appropriate here and `\edge[roof];` can be used instead. I wasn't entirely sure how you wanted the roof to look but here's what I came up with.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.S 
  [.DP [.D Every ] 
    [.NP [.DP_1 \node (ne) {PRO}; ]  
        [.NP $\lambda_1$ 
            [.NP [\edge[roof]; \node (ue) {some company};]
                [.S 
                    [.$\lambda_1$     ] 
                    [.NP    [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {t$_{1}$} ;  ] 
                            [.N$’$ [.N representative ] [.PP [.P of ] 
                                            [. \node [circle,draw] (le) {t$_{2}$} ;   ]
                                            ]
                            ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
  [.VP [.V saw ] [. \qroof{a sample}.DP ]]
]
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south:5) and +(south:6) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:3) and +(south:3) .. (ne);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.VP John [.V$’$ [.V loves ] \qroof{the man}.DP ]]
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagebreak

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [ .TP I [ .T\1 T\\{[past]} [ .\node(vp){vP}; { } [ .v\1 v\\saw 
      [ .VP { } [ .V\1 V\\(saw) [.\node(nP){nP}; \edge[roof]; {a man} ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives,

[image]